Can't create second celery queue
I want to create two celery queues (for different types of tasks)
My celery configuration. I expect that this config creates two queues 'celery' and 'celery:1' 
# celery.py

import os
from celery import Celery

from core_app.settings import INSTALLED_APPS

# this code copied from manage.py
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' app.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core_app.settings')

app = Celery("my_app")

# To start scheduling tasks based on priorities 
# you need to configure queue_order_strategy transport option.
# ['celery', 'celery:1',] - two queues, the highest priority queue will be named celery
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'priority_steps': list(range(2)),
    'sep': ':',
    'queue_order_strategy': 'priority',
}

# read config from Django settings, the CELERY namespace would make celery 
# config keys has `CELERY` prefix
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# load tasks.py in django apps
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: INSTALLED_APPS)

I am defining and running celery task like this:
@shared_task(queue="celery", soft_time_limit=600, time_limit=650)
def check_priority_urls(parsing_result_ids: List[int]):
    check_urls(parsing_result_ids)


@shared_task(queue="celery:1", soft_time_limit=600, time_limit=650)
def check_common_urls(parsing_result_ids: List[int]):
    check_urls(parsing_result_ids)

# running task
check_priority_urls.delay(parsing_results_ids)

But I see only one queue
celery -A core_app inspect active_queues
->  celery@d1a287d1d3b1: OK
    * {'name': 'celery', 'exchange': {'name': 'celery', 'type': 'direct', 'arguments': None, 'durable': True, 'passive': False, 'auto_delete': False, 'delivery_mode': None, 'no_declare': False}, 'routing_key': 'celery', 'queue_arguments': None, 'binding_arguments': None, 'consumer_arguments': None, 'durable': True, 'exclusive': False, 'auto_delete': False, 'no_ack': False, 'alias': None, 'bindings': [], 'no_declare': None, 'expires': None, 'message_ttl': None, 'max_length': None, 'max_length_bytes': None, 'max_priority': None}

1 node online.

And celery flower see only one queu

My celery in docker-compose
celery:
    build: ./project
    command: celery -A core_app worker  --loglevel=info --concurrency=15 --max-memory-per-child=1000000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
    # environment variables declared in the environment section override env_file
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis



your case means your worker is not actually listening on the second queue,
By default, a Celery worker will listen only on the “default” queue unless you explicitly configure or instruct it to do otherwise
you can do something like this
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue, Exchange

app = Celery("my_app")

# Declare your queues explicitly
app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('celery',    Exchange('celery'), routing_key='celery'),
    Queue('celery:1',  Exchange('celery'), routing_key='celery:1'),
)

# (Optional) If you want to direct certain tasks to certain queues,
# you can specify task_routes.
app.conf.task_routes = {
    'path.to.check_priority_urls': {'queue': 'celery'},
    'path.to.check_common_urls':   {'queue': 'celery:1'},
}

# You can keep the rest of your config as is

also you need to make sure your worker listens on both queues
celery -A core_app worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=15 \
       --max-memory-per-child=1000000 \
       -Q celery,celery:1

and at your docker file you need to add this comamand
make sure you add queues in command
command: >
      celery -A core_app worker
      --loglevel=info
      --concurrency=15
      --max-memory-per-child=1000000
      -Q celery,celery:1 


